# Rearranging python data frame index and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert this dataframe (note that 'ABC' is the index name):

```
       t1    t2    t3 
ABC
gp      7    11    26
fp      6    14    23
pm      3    -1     7
wm      2    -2     9
```

to this dataframe:

```
     s1   tx    gp   fp   pm   wm 
0   ABC   t1     7    6    3    2
1   ABC   t2    11   14   -1   -2
2   ABC   t3    26   23    7    9
```

What's the best way to perform this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
df = df.T
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={"index":"tx"}, inplace=True)
df["s1"] = "ABC"
```

Comment: df.T.rename_axis(‘tx’).reset_index().assign(s1=df.index.name)  I think putting iloc[:, np.r_[-1, :-1]] at the end might work to reorder the columns